# use stream_socket_client to retrieve 2 remote files at the same time

Tags: php, stream-socket-client

I have a script in PHP which retrieves two very similar files and performs some tasks on the data then outputs a result. I'm currently using curl and getting one, processing it, then getting the other and processing it.

I want to switch to stream_socket_client as I've heard you can retrieve both files at the same time and do the processing once they have been retrieved but I am unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this blog post](http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254). Basically, you open both sockets, call stream_set_blocking with false, and in a loop you call fread until both streams reach EOF.

Comment: only saved 1-2 seconds but it all adds up